# What is the meaning of the cons "::" operator right after the "new" key word in this code snippet?

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming

I'm studying Scala and see in a tutorial the following definition.
There are 3 "`::`". My understanding is that the first "`::`" is a method in `class List`, and the third "`::`" is a class name.

But I cannot understand the meaning of the second "`::`".

```
sealed abstract class List {
  def ::(head: Int): List = new ::(head, this)
}
case object Nil extends List
case class ::(head: Int, tail: List) extends List
```

Comment: `new ::()` invokes the creation (constructor) of the `::` class as defined by the `case class ::(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new ClassName(constructorArguments)` creates a new instance of the class `ClassName`, passing the `constructorArguments` as constructor arguments.

In your example, `::` is the class-name, and `head` and `this` are the constructor arguments.

(See https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/classes.html for more information about constructors.)

Comment: Thank you. So `::` can be both a method name and a (derived) class name. And in the code snippet the base class invokes the constructor of the derived class. This is really weird since from my understanding base class should be unaware of derived class.

Comment: @CodingNow: That's not the case for sealed base classes, which can't be extended and have to be defined along with their derived classes. So they can know every derivation.

Comment: @CodingNow: There are many cases where base classes refer to derived classes. For a trivial example, consider `java.lang.Object`, whose `toString` method has return-type `java.lang.String`.